# MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall - checking if an environment variable is empty

Tags: powershell, docker, environment-variables

I'm trying to check whether an environment variable is empty or unset in my PowerShell script. The script is running in a Docker container, and intended to pull new code if an environment variable is defined:

```
CMD if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { \
        Write-Host Git pull started; \
        PortableGit\bin\git.exe pull; \
    }; \
```

I get a bunch of errors:

```
web_1     | At line:1 char:110
web_1     | + ... ence = 'SilentlyContinue'; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDA ...
web_1     | +                                                                  ~
web_1     | Missing ')' in method call.
web_1     | At line:1 char:110
web_1     | + ... ue'; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { Wr ...
web_1     | +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
web_1     | Unexpected token 'env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB' in expression or statement.
web_1     | At line:1 char:110
web_1     | + ... ence = 'SilentlyContinue'; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDA ...
web_1     | +                                                                  ~
web_1     | Missing closing ')' in expression.
web_1     | At line:1 char:110
web_1     | + ... ue'; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { Wr ...
web_1     | +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
web_1     | Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
web_1     | At line:1 char:132
web_1     | + ... e'; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { Wri ...
web_1     | +                                                                 ~
web_1     | Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
web_1     | At line:1 char:133
web_1     | + ... '; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { Writ ...
web_1     | +                                                                 ~
web_1     | Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
web_1     | At line:1 char:134
web_1     | + ... ; if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB))) { Write ...
```

I'm not sure how to begin here. The errors seem redundant, but there isn't a clear starting place. Could it have something to do with how Docker parses commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PowerShell variables, including environment variables, must always be referred to with sigil `$`**

Therefore, `env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB` must be **`$env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB`**

To simply **test if an environment variable is defined / has a value**, you don't strictly need `-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty(...)`; instead, you can **take advantage of PowerShell's implicit Boolean conversion**:

- **`$null` or the empty string** is considered **`$False`**
- and any **nonempty** string **`$True`**

To put it all together:

```
CMD if ($env:UPDATE_FROM_GITHUB) { \
        Write-Host Git pull started; \
        PortableGit\bin\git.exe pull; \
    }; \
```